# Where do I load the object to be displayed in a FormView?

Tags: django, formview, django-forms, django-1.4

I'm working with a Django FormView.  I've been looking all over but I can't find an example for how to load an object if PK is provided.

Currently I just set the form_class to a ModelView form.  I want to use this view to either load an empty object if no pk is given, or load the form with the specific object if a pk is provided via the url.

I don't know if I need need to load it in get_form_kwargs or get_form or somewhere else.  I'd really just like a tutorial on how to do it that way.  I do not want to use CreateView or UpdateView, only FormView.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it in `get_form_kwargs`. That should return a dictionary of kwargs to pass into the form. For example if the `pk` is in the url:

```
class MyAwesomeFormView(FormView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form_kwargs = super(MyAwesomeFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        if 'pk' in self.kwargs:
            form_kwargs['instance'] = models.AwesomeModel.objects.get(pk=int(self.kwargs['pk']))
        return form_kwargs
```